# Relay rating for 390 V solenoid

Tags: dc, coil, solenoid

I saw a video using car relay 12V/40A for a solenoid using 390 VDC and about 80A.

[image]

https://youtu.be/fVGrYoqn-EU

https://youtu.be/GsnxzMAczHU

I know relay can suppress the back-EMF from coil.

I want to know how that guy used this small relay to power this huge powerful solenoid without damage or explosion!!!

Comment: a relay consists of two separate devices ... the solenoid and the contacts ... each of the two devices has its own electrical rating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components are generally overbuilt and the effects of overload aren't always "instantaneous and catastrophic failure".  Take a look at the datasheet for [this automotive relay](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=V23134-X0000-A002&DocType=DS&DocLang=English): insulation (including terminal to terminal) rated to 500VRMS, ISO 7637-1 test to 86.5V, overload at 1.35x rated contact current for half an hour, etc.  You can push it past what it's designed to operate at within certain limits.  The relay in the video probably would work a few times, but the increased contact erosion, internal heating, and other effects from severe overload will drop the number of successful operations from 10s of thousands to a few dozen, if that.

You might also consider that just because something "works" in a random YouTube video does not mean that it is a practice to be emulated.